# How to convert byte array to string while keeping all "."?

Tags: java, encoding, character-encoding, binary, byte

I am trying to convert an array of bytes into a String. This is part of a udp packet containing "www.google.ca".

```
byte[] QDNBArray = [3, 119, 119, 119, 6, 103, 111, 111, 103, 108, 101, 2, 99, 97, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

String s = new String(QDNBArray, "UTF-8");
```

why am I getting "wwwgoogleca" instead of "www.google.ca" ?

In Eclipse I even see this : [image: not working]

I tried many Character sets but I can't seem to  find what I am doing wrong.

Thank you in advance,

Guillaume

Comment: How did you come up with  the content of `QDNBArray`?

Comment: A dot should be `46`. Where did `6` and `2` come from?

Comment: Look at your byte array.  None of the "dots" are actually dots.  What encoding are you using?  Look up `3`, `6` and `2` and see what the characters are.

Comment: I am running a local homemade dns server in java( School homework). then using a cmd I did a nslookup for www.google.ca and just filtered the part containing the  Qualified Domain Name(www.google.ca).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The array of bytes does not contain www.google.ca

Instead, it looks like it contains three separate sequences of characters, where each sequence is prefixed by a single byte containing the sequence's length in bytes.  This is a reasonably garden-variety format for sending strings in binary packets.

So you get 3 www 6 google 2 ca

My guess is that you are supposed to recognize each of the strings as a DNS name component, and assemble them yourself into a dot-delimited string.

Do you have a good spec for the UDP packet you are trying to read?  That should have more information.

(I see you are trying to answer DNS requests.  The DNS protocol is documented in the RFC: [RFC 1035](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1035.txt)  The QNAME part of the packet corresponds to what you've found.)

Comment: Thank you @antlesoft this make so much sense now !